# method won't return value cant use an object as array php

Tags: php, oop, methods

I want to get the variables one by one what am I doing wrong, and why cant I get all the array echoed out ?

```
<?php
class get_all{
public $id;
public $product_name;
public $price;
public $date_added;
public $det;    
function get_detais(){

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products  ORDER BY id DESC ");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
$det=array();
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));

      }return $det=array($id,$product_name,$price,$date_added);
} else {
    return $det= "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
}
}
?>
```

and here I call the function like an array element:

```
<?php
$det=new get_all;

$det->get_detais();
echo $det[1];
?>
```

Comment: What do you expect echo `$det[1]` to be? $det is an object, not an array.... though you're also using a local var called $det in get_detais() which will confuse anyone trying to read your code. `$returnedArray = $det->get_detais(); echo $returnedArray[1];`

Comment: There are a few more things wrong with the code other than that.  You realize if you have more than one row returned from MySQL that you're going to overwrite the value of `$id` and friends.  So, you're only going to get the last row that you retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by changing the second piece of code to:

```
<?php
$det=new get_all;

$a=$det->get_detais();
echo $a[1];
?>
```

...but that wouldn't work in all cases because (1) `get_details()` may return a string and (2) even if it's an array, it could contain less than two elements. So:

```
<?php
$det=new get_all;

$a=$det->get_detais();
if(is_array($a)&& count($a)>1)
  echo $a[1];
?>
```

As a side note, in your `get_details()` method, doing a `return $var=...` would be pointless, because by `return`ing you exit the function and `$var` is destroyed.

**EDIT**: As @asafreedman pointed out, your method wouldn't work as you'd expect. Your `while` should be something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $det[]=array($id,$product_name,$price,$date_added);
  }return $det;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP. You're running your while loop and continually overwriting all the data you fetch:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $var = $row[...];
}
```

Every time you fetch a new row of data, the `$var` you saved from last time around gets trashed with the new value.

You need to build an array of the data, e.g. something more like

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
```